# Diesel leak by fuel injector on Volvo V50 2007

Tags: diesel, leak, volvo, fuel-injectors, v50

So for a time now there has been diesel undeneath the fuel injectors. Could this be a simple o-ring seal gone rogue? Or a destroyed copper washer?

There seems to be a little puddle of diesel by every injector, but one of them seems to be always more damp/wet than the others. I really don’t have a clue if the whole injector would need to be replaced or if a seal has broke.

Any tips would be appreciated
[image: Image of diesel puddle]

Answer (score 1):

There are no gaskets or seals in the area you circled.  The adapter into the injector is a tapered thread connection, and the connection to the hard injector line is accomplished by a compression flare.

I would take every connection apart, clean everything carefully, and reassemble with the upper end of a proper torque value.

It may just the compression connection to the hard injector lines, you might try just snugging these up a bit to see if that solves the problem.  However, *do not* use an open-end wrench for this; obtain the proper size flare nut wrench.  Do not over-tighten.  While it is difficult to describe the proper torque by feel, yo fill find that even with moderate pressure the nut will simply stop moving.  Tighten no more!

ALL of this assumes perfectly clean flares.  If they have been loose for some time, debris can accumulate between the male and female flares.  No amount of tightening will solve this properly.  Back them off completely and disconnect, check and clean, and then reassemble.

Good luck.

Comment: Got around to doing it just now, and replacing the copper washer and the o-ring solved my problem. Don’t see any diesel after driving now, finally.